# Make a Windows 7 shortcut to a specific pdf page

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts

Is there a way to make a Windows 7 shortcut to a specific pdf page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have Adobe Acrobat Reader installed, you can create a shortcut to a command line that opens a PDF file to a specific page:

```
AcroRd32.exe /A "page=7=OpenActions" myfile.pdf
```

Will open "myfile.pdf" to page 7.

You can find more command line switches [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/commandlineswitches.php#Acrobat).

Comment: I guess I don't understand. Where would the command line go?  I forgot to mention in my original question that the pdf file is local and that I will need many links to different pages of the same pdf file.

Comment: Never mind. I needed the FULL path to the exe AND put in quotes (since there is a space in the path).  Working now. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

In 2021, on Windows 10, it is possible using following commands

Using Acrobat Reader

```
%acrobat%  /A "page=44=OpenActions" "..\Magazines\2021-05.TA-663.Mai.pdf"
```

Using Foxit Reader

```
%foxit% "..\Magazines\2021-05.TA-663.Mai.pdf" /A page=45
```

Using Chrome

```
start chrome "file:///D:\Documents\Magazines\2021-05.TA-663.Mai.pdf#page=44"
```

Using Opera

```
start opera "file:///D:\Documents\Magazines\2021-05.TA-663.Mai.pdf#page=44"
```

Using Edge

```
start msedge "file:///D:\Documents\Magazines\2021-05.TA-663.Mai.pdf#page=44"
```

Using Firefox

```
start firefox "file:///D:\Documents\Magazines\2021-05.TA-663.Mai.pdf#page=44"
```

On my PC, `%acrobat%` and `%foxit%` variables are equal to

```
set acrobat="C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\acroRd32.exe" 
set foxit="C:\Program Files (x86)\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\FoxitReader.exe"
```

All these solutions are working correctly on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little example using `AcroRd32.exe` program.

Every month I receive a customer's magazine named "Test-Achats".

On my PC, I have created a folder in which I put all these magazines.

When I read an interesting article in a magazine, I create a BAT file on which I can click to display directly the good page.

My folder structure is following

```
Test-Achats
    Script
        LOAD-ARTICLES.bat
        2000-00.TA-000.#00.bat
    Magazines
        2021-05.TA-663.Mai.pdf
        2021-06.TA-664.Juin.pdf
        ...
    Favorites
        2021-05.TA-663.#44 - Isolation habitation.bat
```

2021-05.TA-663.#44 - Isolation habitation.bat contains only following line

```
call ..\Script\LOAD-ARTICLE.bat %~n0
```

LOAD-ARTICLES.bat contains

```
::******************************************************************************
::* LOAD-ARTICLE.bat
::******************************************************************************

:: extract filename prefix and page number

set args=%1
set file=%args:~0,14%
set page=%args:~16%

:: find exact name of PDF file

set folder=..\Magazines

for %%x in ("%folder%\%file%*") do set ta-file=%%x

:: load file at given page using Acrobat Reader 

%acrobat% /A "page=%page%=OpenActions" "%ta-file%"
```

I only hope that this example can help other to implement "shortcut" to read quickly some articles in PDF files.

Using this solution, all `%article%.bat` file contains all same line.

The only thing to do is copying sample file named `2000-00.TA-000.#00.bat` and contained in `Script` folder and ... rename it !