# Hyperlink to specific locations in long PDF

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I deal with long .pdfs, sometimes hundreds of pages. I want to be able to link to specific pages, and even better, specific paragraphs, and to trigger those links from an external program such as a mind-mapping program.

In other words, I want the equivalent of the "link to this paragraph" function in Microsoft OneNote, but for a .pdf

It won't do me any good to have the links work within that one .pdf only. Ideally, the link would not only lead to the document on my computer hard drive, but to that particular page or passage, and ideally, open the .pdf to that page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create URL link to the specific section of the PDF file?](https://superuser.com/questions/1384892/how-to-create-url-link-to-the-specific-section-of-the-pdf-file)

Comment: Also this: https://superuser.com/questions/463741/make-a-windows-7-shortcut-to-a-specific-pdf-page